# php database 4 letter minimum?

Tags: php, mysql

php db.  Some of my entries in the db are 3 letters (no varchar needed really).  When I run searches for these entries I get 0 results.

Not sure if this is set in phpadmin or in my code.  I have attached my output snippet, assuming the error is with my line.  (I've cut out preg_replace line).

```
$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != "")
{
$searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, a, b, c, d FROM db WHERE a LIKE '%$searchquery%'";
}
```

And my output snippet:

```
if($count > 0){
$search_output .= "$count result(s) for $searchquery"};
```

When the term is 3 letters - assume it is "get", $scount gives 0.

```
  $search_output = $count results message;
```

Not sure where my "glitch" is. phpadmin or my code?  I suspect my code? But there's nowhere where I assign set a minimum limit....

Comment: Where's the SQL query?

Comment: added the sql query.  also $query=mysql_query($sqlcommand);

Comment: Have you checked to see that $searchquery actually contains a value you are expecting ? If so, can you give us some examples of the result of the preg_replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Mysql with full text search indexes. By default only words with a minimum
of 4 characters are indexed. (This is a setting though)

Read more about it here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

And more specifically here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

The setting `ft_min_word_len` defines the minimum word length.

Depending on the type of search you need to be able to do, the full text search index might not be the thing you should be using. IIRC, for example, you can only search for entire words... So you need to ask yourself if this is what you want.

Comment: how would I change the setting? phpadmin? I suspect it to be more complicated - is there any specific heads up to keep in mind?

Comment: it's a linguistics db.  so i'm leaning toward entire words only....could be wrong on this tho...